# How do I get mssql_connect to work using PHP7?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7

While porting a web app to a server using PHP7, I encounter one problem: I can't get mssql_connect to work. I found out that mssql doesn't work yet (or will never work) on PHP7.

What's the quickest way to connect to MSSQL using PHP7 on Ubuntu (Nginx, php-fpm)?

Comment: What about PDO connection ?

Comment: From [php manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php): This function was REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.
Alternatives to this function include:
`PDO::__construct()`
`sqlsrv_connect()`
`odbc_connect()`

Comment: Has anyone confirmed the above solution?

Comment: I have the same dilemma. PDO doesn't work properly with Stored Proc's. I much prefer PDO. 
Want to upgrade to php 7 but this is big problem. I guess I am gonna have to try to get dblib working with the stored procs.

Comment: maybe you will tell me to RTCA[read the comment above]; but has anyone figured out how to keep PHP7.0, and use old code with mssql_connect, mssql_query, and mssql_fetch_array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The connection function is not `mssql_connect()` anymore. Since php 5.3 it's been deprecated. Now on php 7 this old function vanishes. But don't worry ;) Nowadays you can use the [`sqlsrv_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) function instead.

Keep in mind that in the new method you need to set up the parameters properly. There are some differences. Here comes a little example.

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress, 1542"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (1433 by default)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Successfuly connected.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection error.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

May be this answer comes a bit late for you but I hope it is not too late for someone.

Comment: Why `sqlsrv_connect`? Why not `pdo` or `mysqli`?

Comment: sqlsrv_connect is for Windows only. He asked about  "MSSQL using PHP7 on Ubuntu (Nginx, php-fpm)"

Comment: sqlsrv_connect currently works for me on this - Ubuntu 16.04.1 with PHP Version 7.0.30-0, freeTDS is installed. and msSQL ODBC "sqlsrv" is installed. SQL server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64).

Comment: `sqlsrv` only works if the ODBC driver is also installed, so why use it over FreeTDS ODBC directly?

Answer (score 0):

1.sudo apt-get update install php-sybase

2.

```
$dsn= 'dblib:host=youIP:1433;dbname=XXX;';
$dbusername="sa";
$dbpassword="XXXX";
try
{
    $mspdo = new PDO($dsn,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    $mspdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
    die("database connect error：". $pe->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: There is no sybase support in PHP7